# Lambda as default argument fails

Tags: c++, c++17

I get an error with the latest versions of clang and gcc with this code:

```c++
int main() {
    auto lambda = [] (auto = [] {}) {};
    lambda();
}
```

Clang gives the error:

```c++
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:3:12: error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(auto:1)>) ()'
     lambda();
            ^
prog.cc:2:35: note: candidate: template<class auto:1> main()::<lambda(auto:1)>
     auto lambda = [] (auto = [] {}) {};
                                   ^
prog.cc:2:35: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:3:12: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'auto:1'
     lambda();
            ^
```

Why does this fail?

Comment: You'll need C++14 for generic lambdas. Does that still fail?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes, I'm even compiling with `-std=c++1z`.

Comment: lambda expression is irrelevant. you'd get the same error with `auto = 1`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Type deduction for `auto` does not consider default arguments.

Comment: This is so also for ordinary templates. I find it often helps to think in terms of code transformation. E.g. also for understanding definitions of member functions within a class definition.

Comment: If you need some example code of what fails, [all 3 commented out lines here fail to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70f1e97ad2e24ba9), without the complexity of passing a lambda to a lambda.

Comment: Type deduction for `auto` is the same for templates (minus the `initializer_list` thing). You can't deduce the type of a template argument through its default argument.

Answer (score 13):

Since lambdas are *sugar* for functors, the issue is on the fact template functions are unable to deduce template arguments (`auto`) in this default context.

A lambda can be reduced to the functor struct level by taking in consideration those statements:

*§5.1.2/3 [expr.prim.lambda]*

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type [...]

*§5.1.2/5 [expr.prim.lambda]*

> [...] For a generic lambda, the closure type has a public inline function call operator member template (14.5.2) whose template-parameter-list consists of one invented type
>   template-parameter for each occurrence of auto in the lambda’s parameter-declaration-clause, in order of appearance. [...]

As such the type of your lambda is equivalent to this functor type:

```
struct unnamed
{
    template<typename Auto1>
    auto operator()(Auto1 = []{})
    {
    }
};
```

And your usage is then equivalent to:

```
int main() {
    auto lambda = unnamed();
    lambda();
}
```

The type of `Auto1` is unable to be inferred in this context as specified in *§14.8.2.5/5 [temp.deduct.type]*:

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> [...]
>
> — A template parameter used in the parameter type of a function parameter that has a default argument
>   that is being used in the call for which argument deduction is being done.

Answer (score 2):

Template functions (or methods) do not deduce their type parameters from their default arguments, and a closure with `auto` parameters is merely an object with a template method.

This makes having a default lambda for a template function a bit annoying.

One approach would be to type erase calling an object, without storing it, like so:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template<class Sig>
struct function_view;

template<class R, class...Args>
struct function_view<R(Args...)>{
  void* state;
  R(*f)(void*, Args&&...);

  template<class F, class=std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<std::result_of_t<F&(Args...)>,R>{}>>
  function_view( F&& fin ):
    state(const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(fin)))),
    f( [](void* state, Args&&...args)->R{
      F&& f = std::forward<F>(*static_cast<std::decay_t<F>*>(state));
      return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    })
  {}
  function_view( R(*fin)(Args...) ):
    state(fin),
    f( fin?+[](void* state, Args&&...args)->R{
      R(*f)(Args...) = static_cast<R(*)(Args...)>(state);
      return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }:nullptr)
  {}
  explicit operator bool(){return f;}
  function_view():state(nullptr),f(nullptr){}
  function_view(std::nullptr_t):function_view(){}
  R operator()(Args...args)const{
    return f(state, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
template<class...Args>
struct function_view<void(Args...)>{
  void* state;
  void(*f)(void*, Args&&...);

  template<class F, class=std::result_of_t<F&(Args...)>>
  function_view( F&& fin ):
    state(const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(fin)))),
    f( [](void* state, Args&&...args){
      F&& f = std::forward<F>(*static_cast<std::decay_t<F>*>(state));
      f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    })
  {}
  function_view( void(*fin)(Args...) ):
    state(fin),
    f( fin?+[](void* state, Args&&...args){
      void(*f)(Args...) = static_cast<void(*)(Args...)>(state);
      f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }:nullptr)
  {}

  explicit operator bool(){return f;}
  function_view():state(nullptr),f(nullptr){}
  function_view(std::nullptr_t):function_view(){}
  void operator()(Args...args)const{
    f(state, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

int main() {
  auto f = [] (function_view<void()> x=[]{}) {
    x();
  };
  f();
}
```

As this just works with function pointers, and I have had good experience with gcc inlining simple function pointers, it might not have as high a performance impact as `std::function`.  And unlike `std::function` no virtual tables or heap allocation is involved.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c89fc769750f3904)

For a non-lambda, you can do this:

```
template<class X=function_view<void()>>
void f( X&& x=[]{} ) {
  x();
}
```

which deduces if you pass is an argument, and becomes a function-at-nothing if you don't.  You could also do:

```
struct do_nothing {
  template<class...Args>
  void operator()(Args&&...)const{}
};

template<class X=do_nothing>
void f( X&& x=do_nothing{} ) {
  x();
}
```

which might be easier to optimize.

Comment: haha 5 years ago I thought I knew C++...... i can't even comprehend the easy snippets lol

Comment: @imso 5 years ago, the above wasn't C++

Comment: i know, crazy how some languages progress vs others - or is it just a bias of questions about the newer features? that's probly it..