# Is it possible to define a lambda in C++ with default generic argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, auto

Is it possible to define a lambda in C++ with default generic argument?

```
int main(){
    auto lambda = [](auto i = 0){return i;};
    std::cout<<lambda()<<"\n"; // this does not compile
    std::cout<<lambda(4)<<"\n"; // this does compile
    auto lambda2 = [](int i = 0){return i;};
    std::cout<<lambda2()<<"\n"; // this is also OK
}
```

I wonder if it's possible to reproduce something like this functor, and why not

```
struct Lambda{
    template<typename T=int>
    auto operator()(T i=1){ return i;}
};
```

Comment: Issue with `lambda` is that it would produce something like `struct Lambda{
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(T i=1) const{ return i;}
};
` which cannot be use either as `Lambda{}()`.

Comment: it will be possible with template lambda in C++20

Comment: @Jarod42 But why deduction doesn't work in your example?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240131/lambda-as-default-argument-fails

Comment: @HolyBlackCat:
*"The non-deduced contexts are:
[...]

— A template parameter used in the parameter type of a function parameter that has a default argument that is being used in the call for which argument deduction is being done."*.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a wrapper:

```
template<class F, class DefaultArg>
struct DefaultArgWrapper
{
    F f;
    DefaultArg default_arg;

    template<class... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) {
        return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    decltype(auto) operator()() {
        return f(default_arg);
    }
};

template<class F, class DefaultArg>
DefaultArgWrapper<F, DefaultArg> with_default_arg(F&& f, DefaultArg arg) {
    return {std::move(f), std::move(arg)};
}

int main(){
    auto lambda = with_default_arg([](auto i){return i;}, 0);
    std::cout<<lambda()<<"\n"; 
    std::cout<<lambda(4)<<"\n";
}
```

---

An alternative C++17 solution:

```
template<class... F>
struct ComposeF : F... {
    template<class... F2>
    ComposeF(F2&&... fs)
        : F(std::forward<F2>(fs))...
    {}
    using F::operator()...;
};

template<class... F>
ComposeF<std::decay_t<F>...> composef(F&&... fs) {
    return {std::forward<F>(fs)...};
}

int main() {
    auto lambda = [](auto i) { return i; };
    auto f = composef(lambda, [&lambda](int i = 0) { return lambda(i); });
    std::cout << f() << '\n';
    std::cout << f(1) << '\n';
}
```

A bit sub-optimal though, since there are two copies of `lambda` involved: one copy in `ComposeF`, another is the original `lambda` on the stack. If `lambda` is mutable that would be an issue.

Comment: … with the caveat, that, unlike a "true" default argument, the expression with which `arg` is initialized, is only evaluated once, at the creation of the functor. This can have some possibly unexpected lifetime interactions as well, e.g. when `DefaultArg` is an instance of `std::initializer_list` as in `bool my_is_sorted(const std::vector<int> &v);` … `with_default_arg(my_is_sorted, {1,2,3}) // UB on call`.

Comment: @ArneVogel Your counter-example does not compile because it cannot deduce `DefaultArg` from `{1,2,3}`. You are quite right though about the difference, it can matter somewhere, but I haven't seen production code where it would. Most often the default arguments are trivial types.